# Is there a way to get a matrix with unique rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, unique

I am looking for a way to generate a matrix with integers values within an interval, where each row of the matrix will be unique (i.e. the set of the elements a row consists of will not be exactly the set of the elements of any other row) Basically, I am looking for the row-wise matrix equivalent of:

```
random.sample(range(0, 35), i+1
```

Edit:

The matrix size changes after every iteration. The interval is 0-35.
At the moment i have this implemented

```
for j in range (5):
    comb_elms_list.append(random.sample(range(0, 35), i+1))
```

where basically I create a unique row and append it. But this has the danger that two rows will have the same elements (even in different order).

Comment: What is your interval and what is the size of your matrix? What did you try to solve it? [mcve]? [ask]?

Answer (score 1):

`set()`s can only hold unique elements - tuples are hashable and can be put into a `set`.

Create `tuples` of numbers from an interval and add them into a `set` until the `set`-length matches your amount of rows. Then create a list of lists from the `set`:

```
import random

interval = range(100) # plenty more numbers then neeeded to fill 5*3 w/o repeats

matrix = (5,3)

ranges= set()
while len(ranges) < matrix[0]:
    ranges.add(tuple(random.sample(interval, k=matrix[1])))

matrix = [ list(t) for t in ranges ]

print(matrix)
```

Make sure you have a big enought of an interval, else you'll get the same tuples over and over and your `while` will never finish.

Output:

```
[[23, 16, 93], [50, 60, 38], [86, 12, 3], [35, 28, 89], [77, 47, 36]]
```

---

If you want to use *all* numbers in your range it is easier to shuffle them and partition them:

```
import random

matrix = (5,3)           # dimension of matrix
m = matrix[0]*matrix[1]  # total numbers needed

interval = random.sample(range(m), k=m) # create a shuffled list of the complete range

# partition the list into correctly sized intervals    
k = [ interval[i*matrix[1]:(i+1)*matrix[1]] for i in range(matrix[0])]


print(k) # [[12, 3, 4], [2, 11, 8], [10, 5, 14], [1, 0, 6], [13, 9, 7]]
```

For partitioning you can read more in [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesnt do quite what i was looking for, but this is good enough, thanks!